# node.js oracledb - error "connection.execute is not a function"

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-oracledb

I am working on a simple node.js oracledb crud application where I use an express skeleton structure.
Since I need to make multiple calls to the DB to accomplish DML statements (select/insert/update/delete) I believe it is more convenient to keep the DB connection in a separate file e.g. lib/db.js and call it each time I need to run the DML statements.
Hence it will look like below:
**lib/db.js**

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

async function connection() {
  await oracledb.getConnection({
    user         : "user",
    password     : "password",
    connectString:"hostname"
 });

module.exports.connection = connection;
```

when I try then to import connection in my **routes/index.js** and work with the app as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection  = require('../lib/db');

// SHOW EDIT USER FORM
router.get('/edit/(:id)', function(req, res, next){
connection.execute('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ' + req.params.id, function(err, rows, fields) {
if(err) throw err
// if user not found
if (rows.length <= 0) {
req.flash('error', 'Customers not found with id = ' + req.params.id)
res.redirect('/customers')
}
else { // if user found
// render to views/user/edit.ejs template file
res.render('customers/edit', {
title: 'Edit Customer', 
//data: rows[0],
id: rows[0].id,
name: rows[0].name,
email: rows[0].email                    
})
}            
})
})
```

I get the error

> TypeError: connection.execute is not a function

I believe it is related to how I should use async/await functions...
My project structure looks like [image]

At the moment I establish each time a connection with the db and then execute the statements, which I do not find a good solution...

```
oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        // Error connecting to DB
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 500,
            message: "Error connecting to DB",
            detailed_message: err.message
        }));
        return;
    }

    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY staffno", {}, {
        outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT // Return the result as Object
    }, function (err, result) {
     .....
        }
        // Release the connection
        connection.release(
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("GET / : Connection released");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a connection pool opened when the app first runs.  Then each route can do `connection = await oracledb.getConnection()` which will return a connection from the pool. This works nicely across files.

You'll find it easier to use async/await everywhere.  Check examples like https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/webapp.js

Also look at the series https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/tree/main/javascript/rest-api for ideas.